# Should Legend entries be singular or plural?

Tags: cartography, legend, gis-principle

In a map legend should the entries be singular or plural?  What is correct?  Road or Roads?

A Google image search for "map legend" lead me to conclude there is no consistent way of having a legend entry be singular or plural. The more authoritative maps I've seen have legend entries in singular. (USGS, National Geographic, etc)

**So my question is, in what cases is a plural legend entry correct?**

This guide says singular:
http://gisgeography.com/map-elements-how-to-guide-map-making/
entry 32: Features in Legend are Present and Singular

Example of a legend with singular, and plural entries that I made.
[image: Legends - Singular entries and plural entries]

Comment: I suspect it's a matter of opinion and down to whoever specifies a particular map. I prefer plural unless there is only one feature in that category e.g. Study Area.

Comment: I don't think it's entirely opinion based, seems like a cartographer needs to chime in here because there are reasons I've heard that are valid but I can't remember enough of both reasons to answer it =P Consider that a Legend describes what's in the legend, and those items are singular (you see a single stream symbol), but on the map, the viewer sees many streams. Another discussion I find interesting is why to exclude the "Legend" title from a legend... < separate topic though!

Comment: I've spent a few hours looking on Google and on ESRI Geonet but I can't find anything definitive. Just the entry I linked in my original question. I recall seeing something on Geonet before, but now I can't find it. I posted this same question on GeoNet just now. https://geonet.esri.com/message/630250-should-legend-entries-be-plural-or-singular

Comment: I asked Aileen Buckley ESRI Cartographer about this issue. She thought it was a good question, and she wrote a blog post about his topic on the ArcGIS Blog http://goo.gl/WtmuYC
Can this question be re-opened?

Comment: Your question is re-opened. Thanks for following up with Aileen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I asked Dr. Aileen Buckley, Esri Cartographer for her advice. She wrote a [blog post](http://goo.gl/WtmuYC) that explains when you should use singular and plural for legend items. I asked, ”Is there a cartographic convention or guideline for legend item labels being singular or plural? Do plural labels imply something different if there are both singular and plural entries?”

In summary;

> "As a rule, legend item labels should be singular nouns."...

Also, ”Do plural labels imply something different?”

> Yes, they do. **The most common interpretation of legend item labels that are plural is that there are multiple things of the same type in a single location**."

ArcGIS Blog post "Legend item labels – singular or plural"
https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2016/08/29/legend-item-labels-singular-or-plural/

From her post, this image shows where you should have plural legend entries. One restroom symbol implies multiple restrooms.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is a great question.  I agree that there is no standard for pluralising legend entries.  Typically, I will use the singular form, but often I will make it plural.  In your map, you may only have one waterbody shown.  So, it doesn't make a lot of sense to call it "Waterbodies".  However, I don't think it makes a huge difference, but I suppose, like anything, it depends on your audience.

**Ultimately, what I put on my legends is what my client wants.**

I recently have made a series of maps and the legend text was in Title Case, which is what I typically use.  However, the client requested that only the first word should be capitalised.  As they are paying for the maps, who am I to argue?

Answer (score -1):

We create GIS file names in plurals; e.g. streams.gpkg

We also create GIS file names in singular; e.g. study_area.gpkg

Why any different in a legend.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/222944)